# Blazor | How to change Scheduler Event Distance

Tags: c#, css, razor, blazor

I am using the code (Shown below) which is similar to the example provided on https://blazor.radzen.com/scheduler. Issue I am running into is I'd like the scheduler to only take a little over half the height of the screen. With each day having 4 appointments. How can I remove the "+2 more" displayed when the slot is not large enough. In essence I'd just like to make each appointment height smaller as well as lessen the distance between appointments in a slot so that all 4 can display at the same time with a smaller scheduler. The code below is an example of what I am trying to do with some css already implemented to make the appointment boxes smaller. I noticed each event was originally 1.5rem height and from top down would have "top" be a multiple of 1.5rem. I was hoping for each event to have the height be 1rem and the events in a slot have "top" be a multiple of 1rem. (Example shown below code. Would still like "+2 more" removed). The image above the code is the base view with no css applied through "inspect element".

[image: Image of how scheduler currently looks]

```
@inject DialogService DialogService

<style>
    .rz-event-content {
        line-height:0.75rem !important;
    }

    .rz-event {
        height:1rem !important;
    }


    .rz-scheduler-nav {
        height: 45px;
    }

    .rz-view-header {
        height:22px
    }
</style>

<RadzenScheduler @ref=@scheduler SlotRender=@OnSlotRender style="height: 500px;" TItem="Appointment" Data=@appointments StartProperty="Start" EndProperty="End"
    TextProperty="Text" SelectedIndex="0"
    SlotSelect=@OnSlotSelect AppointmentSelect=@OnAppointmentSelect AppointmentRender=@OnAppointmentRender>
    <RadzenMonthView />
</RadzenScheduler>


@code {
    RadzenScheduler<Appointment> scheduler;
    Dictionary<DateTime, string> events = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>();
    struct Appointment
    {
        public DateTime? Start;
        public DateTime? End;
        public string Text;
    }
    IList<Appointment> appointments = new List<Appointment>
    {
        new Appointment { Start = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), End = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), Text = "Vacation" },
        new Appointment { Start = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), End = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), Text = "Vacation 2"},
        new Appointment { Start = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), End = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), Text = "Vacation 3"},
        new Appointment { Start = DateTime.Today, End = DateTime.Today, Text = "Busy 1"},
        new Appointment { Start = DateTime.Today, End = DateTime.Today, Text = "Busy 2"},
        new Appointment { Start = DateTime.Today, End = DateTime.Today, Text = "Busy 3"},
        new Appointment { Start = DateTime.Today, End = DateTime.Today, Text = "Busy 4"},
        new Appointment { Start = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1), End = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1), Text = "Free 1"},
        new Appointment { Start = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1), End = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1), Text = "Free 2"},
        new Appointment { Start = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1), End = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1), Text = "Free 3"},
        new Appointment { Start = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1), End = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1), Text = "Free 4"},
    };

    void OnSlotRender(SchedulerSlotRenderEventArgs args) 
    {
        // Highlight today in month view
        if (args.View.Text == "Month" && args.Start.Date == DateTime.Today)
        {
            args.Attributes["style"] = "background: rgba(255,220,40,.2);";
        }
    }

    async Task OnSlotSelect(SchedulerSlotSelectEventArgs args)
    {
        
    }

    async Task OnAppointmentSelect(SchedulerAppointmentSelectEventArgs<Appointment> args)
    {

    }

    void OnAppointmentRender(SchedulerAppointmentRenderEventArgs<Appointment> args)
    {
        // Never call StateHasChanged in AppointmentRender - would lead to infinite loop

    }
}
```

[image: Smaller event boxes, closer together]